# write TeX log files in Ubuntu with certain permissions

Tags: pdftex, ubuntu

Is it possible to give the files. including log files, written during pdfLaTeX compilation certain permissions in Ubuntu (e.g. `-rwxrwxr-x`) in advance?

Comment: I don't think it's possible from `pdftex`: it's a problem to be solved with the help of the operating system. I believe the program uses the current “file mode creation mask”. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umask

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by [egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427/egreg), the `umask` command is what you want to use here.

```
$ umask 0000
$ pdflatex example.tex
$ ls example.log
```

This gives all files the permission `-rw-rw-rw-`. The `x` bit is not relevant for these files, as this is the executable bit, and these files are not executable.

The `umask` is set in the environment, so it is also possible to set the `umask` before starting a LaTeX editor (I tested this with kile): `umask 0; kile example.tex`. See `man umask` for more information.

If the files already exists, then kile doesn't change the permissions, so remove the old log files first.